# Windows XP desktop freezes on trying to connect to internet

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking, freeze

My Windows XP desktop runs fine as long as you don't open a browser or try to connect to internet. As and when I try to connect to Internet or open a browser. It freezes and I manually need to restart.

What might be the problem? How to rectify it?

**EDIT:** I tried re-installing all the browsers many times. But no result. Its still the same. It surely freezes, when I'm trying to connect to internet using DSL Modem.

Comment: When you started to face this issue? Have you tried to fix it by restore id you encountered rhis problem earlier? Have you installed any new software may be that causing this problem.

Comment: Well, Just now I reinstalled windows XP but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser of your choice. You could try removing and doing a fresh install of that browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have reinstalled XP then it may well be a faulty network controller of some sort. Try the latest drivers or another network card.